# jQuery - Dynamic inputs are not appending into form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am trying to create a button "Add field" which will add file type inputs dynamically as defined below:

```
$("#addNew").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".gallery-container").append('<div class="col-md-3"><div id="image-preview-'+id+'" class="image-preview"><label id="image-label-'+id+'" for="image-upload-'+id+'" class="image-label">Wybierz plik</label><input type="file" id="image-upload-'+id+'" name="gallery[]" accept="image/*" class="image-upload" /></div><button type="button" class="removeImage btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-block">Usuń plik</button></div>');    
    id++;
});
```

It's adding input fields correctly and each input have a file but when I tried to submit the form (no Ajax, standard), these fields will not be submitted.

When I set this "append" hardcoded in code, i.e. next to "Add field" button, everything is fine, problem is only when dynamically added.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Check if they're inside the form element or not

Comment: Yes, all of them are inside form. Like I said, when I write this code manually, everythink is fine.

Comment: Can you please include the HTML at your question?

Comment: Are you sure `id` is incrementing properly? If it just has a local scope, it may be initializing every time you call the function.

Comment: @Volem It's can hard because it's really large html. freginold - Yes, here everythink is fine too.

Comment: Possible problem is your button type is "submit". Try set button type "button" **<button type="button">**

Comment: submit() is executing in jQuery on button click.

Comment: I think you need to provide the relevant HTML so we can see what's going on.

Comment: "submit() is executing in jQuery" - so it is not a plain form submission.  Show us the code that submits.